# Did you solve the certificate validation error?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

A certificate validation operation took `15019.0726` milliseconds and has exceeded the execution time threshold.

Comment: You may want to add some context to the question and add in what you have tried and/or looked at already.  You may find others had some similar issues if you root around a bit HiNT: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/97408/a-certificate-validation-operation-took-milliseconds-and-has-exceeded-the-execut

Answer (score 1):

I solve this in couple of my farms. option 2 and 3 i used.

- In the Local Group Policy Editor, we changed the Certificate Path
  Validation Settings to disallow automatic updating of certificates,
  but this did not help.  [ Computer Configuration > Windows >
  Security Settings > Public Key Policies > Certificate Path
  Validation Settings]
- In the Hosts file, we added an entry for crl.microsoft.com to point
  to the localhost, 127.0.0.1. That also didn’t seem to have any
  effect on the problem, as we continued to see those errors.
- We then installed SharePoint root certificate on all the SharePoint
  servers, in the Certificate Root Authority Store. We exported the
  out-of-the-box SharePoint certificate using PowerShell, and then
  manually installed on each server. After that we rebooted all the
  servers, and observed the problem reoccurrence –however no further
  issues were seen in the event logs anymore. The following PowerShell
  commands were used:

  $rootCertSP = (Get-SPCertificateAuthority).RootCertificate
     $rootCertSP.Export(“Cer”) | Set-Content C:\rootCertSP.cer –Encoding
  Byte

open mmc `Add snap-in Certificates, Computer account, Local Computer, OK`
In Trusted Root Certification Authority, Certificates, Import certificate export.